# British passport holder working while travelling in the UK

Tags: uk, uk-citizens, work, french-residents

I am a British Citizen with the French EU-Article 50 (Brexit) residency permit, allowing me to live and work in France. I am a permanent employee of a French company (CDI), and I work for them from my home in France.

I would like to spend three weeks in the UK next year, one week working from a coworking space or a friend's house, the other two on holiday, all on the same trip. I'd enter the UK once at the beginning of the three weeks. I'd be travelling on a British passport.

Does British law allow this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you are a British citizen, you are allowed to work in the UK.

The only concern would be if you were doing this longer term, which would cause tax issues for you, but so long as you stay tax resident outside of the UK then you will be fine.

Comment: Might be worth noting that according to https://www.gov.uk/tax-right-retire-abroad-return-to-uk if you work full-time abroad, you can usually visit the UK without becoming resident again for up to 90 days - as long as you work no more than 30 of these days

Comment: While the citizen is allowed to work in the UK, working in the UK _for a French company_ may require legal work on the company part. I'd advise checking with the company HR whether they allow it or not _beforehand_.

Comment: @MatthieuM. highly unlikely as its not a permanent or even long term arrangement.  Whether its against company policy however is a matter for another SE.

Comment: @Moo: I'm the cautious kind ;) Best to get HR (and management) approval beforehand, so that if they refuse, you're not caught short, and if they approve and anything goes belly-up, you're not on the hook for it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - For such a small trip, it's definitely on the side of better to ask forgiveness than permission end for me... Worst that would happen for such a short duraction is a slap on the wrist and him being asked to either take the remainder as leave or curtail his trip